# Mapping using Servlet Annotations not working

Tags: java, servlets

I am using an annotation like this :

```
@WebServlet("/Document/*")
```

and trying t0 redirect using `sendRedirect`

```
response.sendRedirect("Document/manpreet121FECF23A-D4D2-E411-BEC4-FCDD55FFFFFF");
```

am doing it in a servlet which looks like this :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String file = request.getParameter("nameoffile");
        System.out.println(file);
        String completefileName = file + request.getParameter("select1");
        System.out.println(completefileName);
        String emailid = request.getParameter("mailofmod");
        System.out.println(emailid );
        String ConcatUrl  = Authentication.CreateFile(emailid, completefileName);
        System.out.println("url " + ConcatUrl);
        //String a = "SDJGR4WNVFKN";
        String FinalURL = "Document/" + ConcatUrl;
        System.out.println(FinalURL);
        String path = request.getContextPath();
        System.out.println("path " + path);
        System.out.println("before redirect"+ path +"/" +  FinalURL );
        response.sendRedirect( path +"/" +  FinalURL);

    }

}
```

However, it does not work and I get an exception that says:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: AS-WEB-CORE-00089
```

How can I fix this ?

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: AS-WEB-CORE-00089
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:863)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.CollabEdit.Document.doGet(Document.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.CollabEdit.Document.doGet(Document.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.CollabEdit.Document.doGet(Document.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.CollabEdit.Document.doGet(Document.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.CollabEdit.Document.doGet(Document.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.CollabEdit.Document.doGet(Document.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.CollabEdit.Document.doGet(Document.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.CollabEdit.Document.doGet(Document.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.CollabEdit.Document.doGet(Document.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.CollabEdit.Document.doGet(Document.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.CollabEdit.Document.doGet(Document.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.CollabEdit.Document.doGet(Document.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.CollabEdit.Document.doGet(Document.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.CollabEdit.Document.doGet(Document.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.CollabEdit.Document.doGet(Document.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.CollabEdit.Document.doGet(Document.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.CollabEdit.Document.doGet(Document.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.CollabEdit.Document.doGet(Document.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.CollabEdit.Document.doGet(Document.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.CollabEdit.Document.doGet(Document.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.CollabEdit.Document.doGet(Document.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Please add more details : at least the stacktrace and the type and version of servlet container. The best would be a Minimal Verifiable Complete Example.

Comment: Problem is at line 35 in `doGet` not shown here. More details in my answer below.

Comment: Also, If I use some SOP, those are print repeatedly as if there was a loop there.

Answer (score 1):

When using `sendRedirect`, you send a response to client side (normally a browser) with the URL it should get. If the URL has no host part, same host is assumed, and if it does not begin with a `/`, it is added to the URL of the current page.

In your case, you should try to put a `/` in front of the URL (unless you have **strong** reason not to do so) prepended by the context path :

```
contextPath = request.getContextPath();
response.sendRedirect(contextPath + "/Document/manpreet121FECF23A-D4D2-E411-BEC4-FCDD55FFFFFF");
```

If it still does not work directly type the URL in the address bar of you browser :

```
http://host.do.main/appname/Document/manpreet121FECF23A-D4D2-E411-BEC4-FCDD55FFFFFF"
```

and make sure it works.

If it works, but redirect still does not work, spy the actual response sent to the client with a tool like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and report in an edit to your question.

---

Stack trace shows that the problem is in fact completely different (I still leave above answer as reference). According to it, you should have at line 35 of `Document.java` in the `doGet` method a call to `forward` where the servlet tries to forward to itself. That leads to an infinite loop that seems to be detected by the servlet container as a too deeply nested request dispatching.

Comment: I tried that. If I add "/" in the beginning, URL becomes http://localhost:8080/Document/simooo34B4ECF99-E0D2-E411-BEC4-FCDD55FFFFFF instead of http://localhost:8080/CollabEdit/Document/simooo34B4ECF99-E0D2-E411-BEC4-FCDD55FFFFFF. CollabEdit is the application name that should be there in URL.and When I add URL with CollabEdit directly in browser,it still gives the same exception

Comment: Besides, I use just "Document" in sendRedirect it redirects me to Document servlet but not if I append something to doument so what i understand is that annotation is not taking /* thing for URL.

Comment: @Simrankaur : then the problem is not in the redirect part but directly in URL processing.

Comment: URL processing ?How ? Even if I add simplest characters to Document string, it does not work. What could be the reason ? how do I sort it out ?

Comment: Okay, so that error is basically because of using RequestDispatcher.foward("mainn.html") in Document. java. What could be the reason for it ? It works everywhere else just fine.